# How to prompt AWS SNS to send a confirmation message to a Cloudformation-created subscription?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

Via CloudFormation, I am trying to create a queue and subscribe it to an existing topic

```
$ cat ops/queue-and-subscription.yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  Minimal template

Resources:
  Queue:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue'

  Subscription:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::Subscription'
    Properties:
      Endpoint:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - "Queue"
          - "Arn"
      Protocol: "sqs"
      RawMessageDelivery: true
      TopicArn: "<existing Topic ARN>"

Outputs:
  QueueARN:
    Description: "ARN of the queue set up temporarily for testing"
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - "Queue"
        - "Arn"
  QueueURL:
    Description: "URL of the queue. This is required for receiving messages"
    Value: !Ref Queue
$ aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name my-test-stack --template-body file://ops/queue-and-subscription.yaml
{
    "StackId": "<stackId>"
}
[...wait...]
$ aws cloudformation describe-stacks --query 'Stacks[?StackName==`my-test-stack`] | [0].StackStatus'
"CREATE_COMPLETE"
$ aws cloudformation describe-stacks --query 'Stacks[?StackName==`my-test-stack`] | [0].Outputs[?OutputKey==`QueueURL`] | [0].OutputValue'
"<queueUrl>"
$ aws sqs receive-message --queue-url <queueUrl>
[null]
```

I expected that a confirmation message would be put directly onto the queue (which I would need to read and pass to a `confirm-subscription` call [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_ConfirmSubscription.html). However, no such message is ever passed to the queue.

How can I prompt AWS (through SDK, not UI) to send the confirmation message so that I can confirm the subscription?

---

EDIT: I should note that I just tried a similar approach, but creating the SNS Topic within the template (and referring to it with `!Ref Topic`) - same behaviour, no confirmation message.

---

EDIT2: I suspect that this is because I haven't provided an [SQS Queue Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.cloudformation.html). Trying that now.

Answer (score 0):

Once I added a [QueuePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-policy.html) allowing the Topic to write to the Queue, messages flowed through as expected (without a confirmation message).